# How can I stub/mock a function in a module called by another module in a test?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to test a function in module X. It is a fairly complex function. In this function, I import a function in Module Y that calls a third party service. How can I stub this 3rd party service in Module Y if my tests for module X don't import module Y?

Answer (score 0):

You can patch along the `require` seam with a project like mockery:

> If you've tried working with mocks in Node.js, you've no doubt
>   discovered that it's not so easy to get your mocks hooked up in the
>   face of Node's module loading system. When your source-under-test
>   pulls in its dependencies through require, you want your mocks
>   provided, instead of the original module, to enable true unit testing
>   of your code.

https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your module `X` returns the result of an operation performed by `Y`, we can say that `X` is as follows:

```
const y = require ('y.js');

xWork () {
    return y.doWork().result;
}
```

Here you can update `X` to inject `Y` like this:

```
xWork (y) {
    return y.doWork().result;
}
```

From there you in your test you can generate a mock of `Y` that can be injected like this:

```
yMock = {
    doWork: () => { 
        return { result: 'mockedResult' };
    }
};

x.xWork(yMock); // call x with y mock
```

Javascript allows you to mock anything without requiring any dependency which is perfect for unit testing. Hope it helps.